# DBF to sql Converter

Tags: mysql, dbf

is there any free converter for DBF to Mysql?

Comment: Please specify what platform you're on and what database engine you are on currently. Or do you have the dbase files only?

Comment: We r using mysql5.0 and Java Platform

i have a dbf files i want to convert the dbf data to Mysql sir?

Answer (score 1):

dbf2mysql package for Ubuntu (Linux) works welll.

"*This program takes an xBase file and sends queries to an MySQL server to insert it into an MySQL table and vice versa.*"

Answer (score 1):

Navicat Premium of Navicat for MySQL works well. You can try trial version for free.